# ClojuresScript not applying class values with click

Tags: material-ui, clojurescript, reagent

I have the following over-engineered code that displays 2 buttons on a page, but when I click on a button nothing happens.

I'm using reagent (r) and mui (m).

```
(defn settings [id]
  (let [active "active-content-button"
        inactive "content-button"
        classes (r/atom {1 inactive, 2 inactive})]

    (defn toggle-active [button-id]
      (swap! classes assoc 1 inactive)
      (swap! classes assoc 2 inactive)
      (swap! classes assoc button-id active))

    [:div {:style {:padding (* 2 SPACING)}}
     [:div {:class "tab-block"}
      [m/Button {:class (@classes 1) :on-click #(toggle-active 1)} "Filters"]
      [m/Button {:class (@classes 2) :on-click #(toggle-active 2)} "Settings"]]]))
```

I'm expecting the classes of the buttons to update themselves on click.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

A few thinngs:

- Don't nest `defn` and/or `def`. Instead, use `let`/`letfn`/`fn` or move that `defn` outside
- Don't use multiple `swap!`/`reset!` operations on the same atom. Instead, combine them in a single one
- You need to use a so-called [form-2 component](https://cljdoc.org/d/reagent/reagent/1.2.0/doc/tutorials/creating-reagent-components#form-2--a-function-returning-a-function) or `r/with-let`. Without any of those, your `r/atom` gets re-created on every render of the `settings` component

Some less important things:

- Class names can be keywords in Reagent, if you prefer those
- Mutually exclusive options are better handled with keywords rather than with numbers, i.e. I would remodel your data as `active-button (r/atom :filters)` and then would choose the class conditionally based on that

Answer (score 0):

The [suggestions from the earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75685219/clojuresscript-not-applying-class-values-with-click/75685507#75685507) would look something like this:

```clj
(defn class [active?]
  (if active? "active-content-button" "content-button"))

(defn settings [id]
  (let [active (r/atom :filters)]
    (fn []
      [:div {:style {:padding (* 2 SPACING)}}
       [:div.tab-block
        [m/Button {:class (class (= @active :filters))
                   :on-click #(reset! active :filters)}
         "Filters"]
        [m/Button {:class (class (= @active :settings))
                   :on-click #(reset! active :settings)}
         "Settings"]]])))
```